# Stop Form Submission on Page refresh?

Tags: forms, asp-classic

I have a simple asp form which is used to insert data into the database.It's working fine on click of submit button.But it again submits itself on press of refresh.How t stop the form from doing so?

Answer (score 2):

The following might work:

- Store a unique form data value (timestamp?) in a cookie or session variable and check it to  prevent re-processing ..
- Redirect your page to itself with a GET (see also [snipplr.com/view/35515/](http://snipplr.com/view/35515/)) and check (POST versus GET) on processing the page..